# Why my Tomcat could not load

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

First of all, I want to say that I know that this question is already has been asked but their solutions really did not help me. My problem occurs when I add Tomcat9.0 into my server part in console. When I click to add server and when I then click finish to configure Tomcat I got error:

> Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at \Servers2\Tomcat
>   v9.0 Server at localhost-config. The configuration may be corrupt or
>   incomplete. The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]"
>   is not allowed.

I tried everything(to copy files from tomcat instalation directory to folder Server2 in my workspace, to remove then to add server)... but nothing helps me. My tomcat instalation is on Desktop and that path is set into server-Run time enviroment in eclipse.
Could someone maybe helps me to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to add the tomcat 9 to the neon eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Reinstall your Tomcat 9 (use the default location to start and see if it works).
- Uninstall all the tomcat servers from your servers tab in Eclipse.
- Restart Eclipse.
- Then go to **File -> New -> Other**, select **Server**, select **Apache -> Tomcat v9.0 Server** and hit Next.
- Select tomcat installation directory.
- Hit **Finish**.
- After it shows up in your servers tab, double click on it and select **Use Tomcat installation** and save the changes.
- Make sure your service in windows services set to manual and not started.
- Now you can start it inside the Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The error includes 2 parts:

> Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at *\Servers2\Tomcat
>   v9.0 Server* at localhost-config

You should check the server config file.

> The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not
>   allowed.

This error usually occurs when a XML declaration (eg: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="...">`) is **NOT at the beginning of the file**.

Try searching the file for stray `<?xml`. Also, remove everything before the first `<?xml`, even blanks or byte order mark.